# Browser automatically quit after python function execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

if I launch chrome webdriver from a python function why does it automatically close the browser window after execution and how do I prevent this?
Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
def open_chrome_driver():
    chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Users/User/Documents/pythonfiles/chromedriver.exe')
    return chrome_driver


open_chrome_driver()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the python runtime will clean up all the resources it allocated for its use when the script ends.

put a breakpoint in the last line of code you want to be executed and run it in debug mode (depends on your IDE). Once it pauses, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: hope this helped you out. let me know if you need a bit help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following - it should detach chrome process from chromedriver and prevent from closing.

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

Hope this solves your issue.

You will need to import Options `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`

And off course as Davis Jahn said - you may put a breakpoint

Comment: Thanks so much. I actually found a easier rookie way to do it. All I did was leave driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Users/User/Documents/pythonfiles/chromedriver.exe') and outside of the function and the browser persisted.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to simply return the `chromedriver` object back to a variable with the same name

```
chrome_driver = open_chrome_driver()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).